# Kotlin: coroutineScope is slower than GlobalScope

Tags: performance, kotlin, parallel-processing, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning coroutines, and I encounter the following surprising (for me) behavior. I want to have a parallel map. I consider 4 solutions:

1. Just `map`, no parallelism
2. `pmap` from [here](https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/04/parallel-map-in-kotlin/).
3. Modification of item 2: I removed `coroutineScope` and use `GlobalScope`.
4. Java's `parallelStream`.

The code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.streams.toList
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

inline fun printTime(msg: String, f: () -> Unit) =
    println("${msg.padEnd(15)} time: ${measureNanoTime(f) / 1e9}")

suspend fun <T, U> List<T>.pmap(f: (T) -> U) = coroutineScope {
    map { async { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }
}

suspend fun <T, U> List<T>.pmapGlob(f: (T) -> U) =
    map { GlobalScope.async { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }


fun eval(i: Int) = (0 .. i).sumBy { it * it }

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val list = (0..200).map { it * it * it }
    printTime("No parallelism") { println(list.map(::eval).sum()) }
    printTime("CoroutineScope") { println(list.pmap(::eval).sum()) }
    printTime("GlobalScope") { println(list.pmapGlob(::eval).sum()) }
    printTime("ParallelStream") { println(list.parallelStream().map(::eval).toList().sum()) }
}
```

Output (without sums):

```
No parallelism  time: 0.85726849
CoroutineScope  time: 0.827426385
GlobalScope     time: 0.145788785
ParallelStream  time: 0.161423263
```

As you can see, with `coroutineScope` there is almost no gain, while with `GlobalScope` it works as fast as `parallelStream`. What is the reason? Can I have a solution which has all advantages of `coroutineScope` with the same speed gain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scopes are only indirectly involved in the differences you observed.

`GlobalScope` is a singleton that defines its own dispatcher, which is `Dispatchers.Default`. It is backed by a thread pool.

`coroutineScope` does not define its own dispatcher so you inherit it from the caller, in this case the one created by `runBlocking`. It uses the single thread it is called on.

If you replace `coroutineScope` with `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`, you'll get the same timings. This is in fact how you *should* write this (instead of `GlobalScope`) in order to get sane behavior in the face of possible failures of some of the concurrent tasks.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, if I do `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default)` in `main` instead, it also works faster. Both modifications are still slower than other solutions (`0.21` secs on average), but I guess it makes sense, since we wrap it in coroutine context.

Comment: I benchmarked your program with just one change: doing a constant amount of work in `eval`: `fun eval(i: Int) = (0 .. 10_000_000).sumBy { it * it * i }`. This is enough work to drown out the price of coroutine switching. It may be much cheaper than thread switching, but still isn't as cheap as being invisible next to per-item computation cost. With this function the coroutines are on a par with parallel streams. If you want the same effect for lower per-item cost, then don't supply just one item to each coroutine, supply batches of 1,000 items or whatever makes sense.

Comment: What is the difference between 'GlobalScope' and 'coroutineScope '?

And What is the life of coroutineScope?

Comment: @Shubham The former is a singleton object and the latter is a function which returns the result of the code you pass in. You can't even meaningfully compare them.

Comment: @Shubham What do you mean by "life of a function" exactly? You call it, it completes.

Comment: GlobalScope exits for the whole application's life time and ViewModelScope exits for the  viewmodel's cycler. I want to know coroutineScope's life.

Comment: @Shubham As explained above: `coroutineScope` is a function and not a scope object. Its "lifetime" is from when you call it until it returns.