# CoRoutine Async is not running parallely

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code that I am trying out to run coroutines parallel. However, the code does not run parallel. It takes 30secs for all the stock prices to return instead of 10 secs. However, If I use GlobalScope.launch, it does work correctly. I gather from the documentation that the We should avoid using GlobalScope and use coroutine scope. Can you help in understanding why this is not running in parallel?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun getStockPrice(company: String) : Int{
    println("Fetching Stock Price")
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    return 100
}



fun CoroutineScope.launchCoRoutines() {
    val companies = listOf<String>("Google", "Amazon", "Microsoft")

    launch {

        var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val sharePrice = mutableListOf<Deferred<Int>>()
        for (company in companies) {
            sharePrice += async {
                getStockPrice(company).toInt()
            }
        }

        for (share in sharePrice) {
            println(share.await())
        }
        var endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        println(endTime - startTime)

    }


}

 fun main()  {
     runBlocking{
         launchCoRoutines()
     }
     println("Request Sent")
    Thread.sleep(55000)
}
```

Comment: You're running your coroutines on the main thread and `Thread.sleep(10000)` is blocking it. Change `Thread.sleep ` for `delay` which suspends the thread instead of blocking it.

Comment: use `async` with `Dispatchers.IO` `async(Dispatchers.IO) { getStockPrice(company) }`

Comment: @IR42 Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found here:

> [Kotlin: coroutineScope is slower than GlobalScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531464/kotlin-coroutinescope-is-slower-than-globalscope)

as said:

> coroutineScope does not define its own dispatcher so you inherit it
>   from the caller, in this case the one created by runBlocking. It uses
>   the single thread it is called on.

EDIT: 
you could use this function

```
fun launchCoRoutines() {
    val companies = listOf<String>("Google", "Amazon", "Microsoft")

    launch(Dispatchers.Default) { // will get dispatched to DefaultDispatcher 

        var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val sharePrice = mutableListOf<Deferred<Int>>()
        for (company in companies) {
            sharePrice += async {
                getStockPrice(company).toInt()
            }
        }

        for (share in sharePrice) {
            println(share.await())
        }
        var endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        println(endTime - startTime)
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: 
See @Animesh Sahu comment, it is the best answer

Comment: I am not sure I get it. If I have to rewrite this with coroutine context, how can I rewrite this for better performance? @benjiii

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan don't use Thread.sleep and use `suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {...}` instead of `runBlocking`

Comment: Thanks @AnimeshSahu for your response. It works. Can you provide any documentation/book/video that explains this concept?

Comment: as said @AnimeshSahu, you should not use Thread.sleep nor use runBlocking. Also, see my edit, you could replace launch {} with lauch{Dispatchers.Default} to dispatch your coroutines on another thread

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan there is a slack discussion over that on official kotlinlang slack https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C1CFAFJSK/p1573835871252800?thread_ts=1573793616.245000&cid=C1CFAFJSK he says "I think it’s slightly different – `suspend fun main` will _start_ executing on the main thread, but if you look at `coroutineContext` it’s `EmptyCoroutineContext`, which implies `Dispatchers.Default`, and any coroutines started from the scope will be executed on the default pool."
https://pl.kotl.in/HZUd3SohR since then https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines official docs recommend